# Python max value from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate max/min from a text file containing numbers, but can't figure out how. I was able to do count and total, but not max/min. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
def main():
    counter = 0
    total = 0
    inputFile = open('Numbers.txt', 'r')

    for numbers in inputFile:
        numbers = float(numbers.rstrip())

        total += numbers
        counter += 1   

    print('Count:', counter)
    print('Total:', total)
    print('Average:', total / counter)

    inputFile.close()

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by max/min? Is your file contains just numbers? Else if it contains words, you want max/min of the length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler way to achieve what you are doing is:

```
num_list = [float(num) for num in inputFile.read().split())
# OR, num_list = map(float, inputFile.read().split())

counter = len(num_list)
total = sum(num_list)

# Your desired values
max_val = max(num_list)
min_val = min(num_list)
```

---

In case you want to do it in your code, you may do:

```
min_value, max_value = 999, -999  # Range based on the value you are sure you data will lie within

for numbers in inputFile:
    numbers = float(numbers.rstrip())
    # ... your other logic
    if min_val > numbers:
        min_val = numbers
    if max_value < numbers:
        numbers = numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with numbers, I'd suggest using the `numpy` module. With it, you can achieve what you want very quickly - depending on your input file:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.loadtxt("Numbers.txt")
print('Total:', np.sum(x))
print('Average:', np.average(x))
print('Max:', np.amax(x))
print('Min:', np.amin(x))
```

and much more... if your input file isn't as simple to read, you can try using [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to extract the data.